# Meaning of "I'm surprised you ever do that."

Tags: meaning

While reading some quotes from a book, I came across a quote consisting of the phrase whose structure I found hard to figure out.

*"You're so slow. I'm surprised **you ever get anywhere**."*
(From Aesop's fables)

Does this sentence roughly mean *"I'll be surprised if you ever get anywhere"*? If it does, could you give me some examples like this one?

Thanks.

Comment: There’s no future implied. It’s a simple present tense, and that’s what it means. Obviously, the tortoise, despite being slow, does manage to get _somewhere_ some of the time. The hare is making a hyperbolic statement that he is surprised the tortoise ever manages to get to any place at all, at any time, when it’s so slow in moving.

Comment: You "misparse" the cited text. Assume a deleted ***that*** rather than ***if*** after ***surprised***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are very slow, it surprises me that, at any time, you can get anywhere.

> "**ever**" (adv) [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ever)
>
> - **at any time** - "I love you more than ever before."
> - **in any way** - "How can I ever thank you for that?"

Look at these similar examples:

- I wonder whether this kind of question has ever been asked before.
- Did it ever occur to you that I might disapprove?
- Don't you ever regret letting him go away.